# XSLT 1.0: Concatenate attributes from child nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm having some trouble with xslt and was hoping that maybe someone here can help me:

My xml-file that looks like this:

```
<garden>
  <appletree>
    <fruit name="a" />
    <fruit name="b"/>
    <fruit name="c"/>
    <fruit name="d"/>
  </appletree>

  <appletree>
    <fruit name="e" />
    <fruit name="f"/>
    <fruit name="p"/>
    <fruit name="h"/>
  </appletree>

 <appletree>
    <fruit name="e" />
    <fruit name="f"/>
    <fruit name="q"/>
    <fruit name="r"/>
  </appletree>
</garden>
```

Now I'd like to assign keys to the appletree-nodes, consisting of the concatenated name attributes of their fruit-children. So the key for the first tree would be 'abcd', for the 2nd tree 'efph' and for the third tree 'efqr'.

I tried the following:

```
<xsl:key name="key" match="appletree" use="fruit/@name" />
```

'fruit/@name' returns a set of all name attributs, but only the first one is used as key. The others are ignored. So basically what I need there is a function that does something like this: concat(fruit[1]/@name, ..., fruit[n]/@name).

Is there such a function in XSLT 1.0? (I can't use XSLT 2.0, which I think would make this much easier.)

I'd really appreciate a little help, because I'm really lost here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but there's no reason you can't just use concat, with 'n' being the most you'll ever find.

`concat(fruit/@name,fruit[2]/@name,fruit[3]/@name,fruit[4]/@name,fruit[5]/@name)`

If there's only 4, the last one will just be ignored, and it'll use the length 4 value. NB: You don't need the `[1]` on the first one, it'll give you that by default anyway.

Any other solution is likely to be significantly more complicated. I can think of one way using a two-pass approach, but it'll make the code much less readable and maintainable.

Comment: I tried pretty much everything except the solution you suggested... This works great for me, especially because I know more or less in advance how many 'fruits' I have to deal with. Thanks a lot!